# Move button Right to left animation iOS - swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-animations

I am creating an application with some buttons in a view controller. I want to add one animation like all the buttons are move from right to left. But all my buttons are moving from left to right. Here is my code.

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        b1_center_alignment.constant -= self.view.bounds.width;
        b2_center_alignment.constant -= self.view.bounds.width;
        b3_center_alignment.constant -= self.view.bounds.width;
        b4_center_alignment.constant -= self.view.bounds.width;
        b5_center_alignment.constant -= self.view.bounds.width;
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated);
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.b5_center_alignment.constant += self.view.bounds.width
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.3, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.b4_center_alignment.constant += self.view.bounds.width
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)


        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.6, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.b3_center_alignment.constant += self.view.bounds.width
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.9, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.b2_center_alignment.constant += self.view.bounds.width
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 1.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.b1_center_alignment.constant += self.view.bounds.width
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil);

    }
```

I am very new to ios development. Please someone help me to solve this issue. Here  `b1_center_alignment, b2_center_alignment` are center horizontal constraints from `storyboard`.

Comment: Have you tried `-=` instead of `+=`?

Comment: You mean  b1_center_alignment.constant += self.view.bounds.width; in viewwill appear and self.b1_center_alignment.constant -= self.view.bounds.width like this in viewdidappear right?

Comment: Yes. Does that work?

Comment: I also think the same ant try to do like that and the response is buttons moving from right to left but it is not completed. the issue is initially buttons are in its origional position and animation move top of the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
b1_center_alignment.constant -= self.view.bounds.width;
```

You're hiding the button on the left side of the screen, and then with

```
self.b5_center_alignment.constant += self.view.bounds.width
```

you move it back to it's original position

You need to invert the signals

```
b1_center_alignment.constant += self.view.bounds.width;
```

and
    self.b5_center_alignment.constant -= self.view.bounds.width

Comment: I also think the same ant try to do like your answer and the response is buttons moving from right to left but it is not completed. the issue is  initially buttons are in its origional position and animation move top of the button.

Comment: Did you understand what i mean? If not please tell me i'll add the screenshot

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand

Comment: I found the issue but don't know how to fix it. My problem is I set the leading space for buttons that is the issue. Once I remove the leading space width is changing. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you don't need the leading space constraint. You need the center alignment and width constraints.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how to set the width. Because it is changing.

Comment: I suggest you study iOS auto layout a little more through this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2), I think it will help you understand your problem a lot better

Comment: Thanks, I fixed my issue. One more change I did I just remove leading space and add trailing space. Everything is perfect.